# Magento product view's jQuery issue

Tags: php, jquery, magento

I have included below code as css fix was not viable. It worked however now I cannot get pre-existing javascripts to work! Is there a reason why? I want to get the menu to toggle which was working before so when clicked it toggles to another text.

this is the link if you need to have a look:
    http://www.playerspriority.wmetools.com/shop/index.php/pro-peptide.html

Thank you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var n = $('select').length;
if(n == 2){
$('.product-collateral').attr('id','two-select-boxes');
}
$('div.zoom').attr('style','display:none');
$('p.zoom-notice').attr('style','display:none');
$('p.product-image-zoom').removeClass('product-image-zoom');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know magento uses prototype, which can lead to some problems with the `$` variable. Run your jQuery code in no-conflict mode and try again.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.noConflict();
    // replace $. with jQuery.
    //e.g.
    jQuery('.product-collateral).attr('id','two-select-boxes');

});
```

It is also a good practice to wrap your jQuery code into a ready function, to be sure the DOM is fully loaded before the jQuery code could run.

Comment: Hi it's working with noconflict thank you but now var n = $('select').length;  is not working. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you using firebug? Or the chrome developer tools? This should make finding bugs/causes easier.

Comment: I'm using firebug would you have to check dom inspector? Or should I be better off writing this code in prototype?

Comment: Sorry to ask again but how would you chage this into Prototype?     var n = $('select').length;
     if(n == 2){ 
     $('.product-collateral').attr('id','two-select-boxes');
     }
     $('div.zoom').attr('style','display:none');
     $('p.zoom-notice').attr('style','display:none');
     $('p.product-image-zoom').removeClass('product-image-zoom');

Comment: I just used jQuery instead of $ and it worked! Thank you very much. Here is my code.  $(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery.noConflict();
 n = jQuery('select').length;
 if(n == 2){ 
 jQuery('.product-collateral').attr('id','two-select-boxes');
 }
 $('div.zoom').attr('style','display:none');
 $('p.zoom-notice').attr('style','display:none');
 $('p.product-image-zoom').removeClass('product-image-zoom');
 });